# Grant private access to S3 bucket via aws api gateway: Set up a proxy integration with a proxy resource

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy, private, api-gateway, bucket

Unable to configure Apigateway as a proxy for a private S3 bucket.

I am using the AWS service integration section in the link (https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-s3-website-proxy) to grant private access to a s3 bucket.

I cant get a generic route to work. Able to set up a route in api gateway for index.html.

After loading the index.html the script tags (links which reside in s3) inside the html are not fetched in the browser via Apigateway url because a route is not configured in apigateway.

I have tried using the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html to set up a generic route to forward to S3 but its not working.

Thanks for reading.